# Como aumentar la version del assembly desde comando

Tags: packages, nuget

Estoy generado paquetes nuget con el comando nuget package.

¿Es posible aumentar la versión del assembly, dentro de AssemblyInfo.cs para llevar un mejor control de los ensamblados?

Gracias!